# Unable to create database using DBCA

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have installed Oracle 11g on Windows 7 successfully. But, when I am creating a database using DBCA, it says init.ora (access denied), at the last step, and stops. I logged into the system using admin.

I have manually changed the settings of that directory where the DB file is created. But have had no success. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is in Oracle 12c running on my Windows 10 PC.

Right click on the "CMD" before opening the command prompt and

Click on "RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR" so the command prompt opened with Full Administrator privileges

Call the "DBCA" assist by typing DBCA in this command window

The database creator assistant opens, and everything after this step goes very well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you haven't followed the installation guide. A typical error if you have not added the user to the domain group.

Answer (score 0):

I jumped into the same issue today. The issue will keeping come out no matter you're logged in as admin or not (in most cases, we logged in as admin, same as me).

I get pass the issue as : press Windows key to open Start Menu, type in 'dbca', when dbca.bat shows up in Programs, right click and select 'Run as administrator', everything goes fine now !